# Why does my Arduino 3.3v fluctuate?

Tags: arduino-mega

[image: Imgur]

For some reason, my 3.3v on my Arduino is fluctuating a lot, and I am not sure why.
The multimeter is measuring dc voltage and is connected between GND and 3.3v of an Arduino Mega.

The multimeter works fine. Connecting between 5v and GND gives 5V on multimeter.

Comment: the video is meaningless ... it does not show what you are measuring

Comment: Im measuring DC voltage between gnd and 3.3v

Comment: @jsotola can you tell me what information I should include?

Comment: you have to disconnect everything from the board, upload a blank sketch and measure it again.

Comment: Tried that still fluctuated

Comment: First check your connections. Otherwise: broken 3.3V regulator or too much load on the 3.3V supply.

Comment: Change the batteries in your meter. Try measuring things with your oscilloscope rather than your meter.

Comment: What happens if there is a load on the 3.3V rail. It kind of looks like the point you are measuring is floating/not connected. Try adding a 1kOhm resistor between 3.3V and GND, and remeasure. If it's indeed floating you should read 0V. Also try a different GND pin, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino output voltages may "fluctuate" a few mV but what you showing us in that gif is really unstable.

What you should be doing is:

1. Disconnect everything from Arduino except the power source
2. measure the voltage again;

Is it stable? the problem was because of pulling too much current that causing voltage drop and instability .

Is it unstable?

3. Try checking with another MM and/or change auto-range to manual.

Is it stable when measuring the voltage with another MM? something was wrong with your previous MM.

Still unstable?

4. Connect the Arduino to a 9V power adapter and disconnect the USB cable.

Measure the voltage again, if it's stable the problem was because of some error in the cable or USB power source.

Voltage is still unstable?

5. change the 3.3V voltage regulator.

It should fix the problem if not report back to do some more in-depth problem solving.

Comment: My voltage Reg was off I should have tested before asking, but thanks!

Comment: @SanjitSarda Just for my curiosity, what do you mean with "my voltage reg was off"? Was it broken or did you switched it off. If you switched it off, how did you do that?